# "To location array" to index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, permutation, shuffle

I have some data array

```
a = [6,4,3,1,5]
```

and a "to location array", that gives indices for how these elements should be reshuffled,

```
b = [4,2,0,1,3]
```

What this means: the 1st element of `a` should go to index 4, the 2nd element of `a` should go to index 2, and so on. So when applying `b` to `a`, I should get:

```
c = [3,1,4,5,6]
```

However, I am struggling to implement this operation. Is it a common operation? If so, could someone give me an example? I want to generate some array `d` from `b` so that

```
c = a[d]
```

In the above example,

```
d = [2,3,1,4,0]
```

**What I tried:** `d = b[b]`, but this is not always correct.

Comment: You can get `c` without computing `d`

Comment: @Ivan I would also like to know that, but it is probably a for loop? the reason I want `d` is so that I (hopefully) don't need a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I just found is calculating `d` is as follows:

```
d = np.zeros(5);
d[b] = np.arange(5)
```

But it seems very non-intuitive to me.

Comment: What's intuition have to do with this?  :)  Wait, didn't you  wean `d[b]=a`?  Intuitively, ask what you want `d[b]` to look like after the assignment.  In the compiled numpy code, often a target array of the right size is created, and then the values are copied to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `d`, you can directly get `c` with [`np.put_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html#numpy.put_along_axis):

```
>>> a = np.array([6,4,3,1,5])
>>> b = np.array([4,2,0,1,3])

>>> c = np.zeros_like(b)
>>> np.put_along_axis(c, b, a, 0)

>>> c
array([3, 1, 4, 5, 6])
```

Note the operation is *inplace*.